# TIme complexity of two reversed sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, language-agnostic

What would be the time complexity of two reversed arrays merge into one sorted array?

Is it O(n) or O(log n)?

Comment: Depends on the algorithm.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i'm sorry i'm new in here and also new to this kind of stuff so i thought that java would be also appropriate since it revolves around our subject. I accidentally remove also the language-agnostic tag

Comment: @amateur0724 No worries! The question is back to looking good now I think and I added two more tags to hopefully attract more attention to the question.

Comment: Btw, I looked it up @ [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort): _"In sorting_ n _objects, merge sort has an average and worst-case performance of O(n log  n)."_ so neither alternative seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of the given arrays are in reversed sorted order it would be `O(m + n)(m - length of 1. array, n - length of 2. array)` because you need to iterate linearly through both arrays.

But if arrays are not sorted you have 2 options:

1. To sort them and after sorting to merge them `O(nlogn + mlogm)`.
2. To concatenate arrays and to sort that concatenated array `O(nlogn + mlogm)`.